# How to quickly find the fully qualified name of a class in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I been giving IntelliJ a spin, and loving it so far. But, I got a question, is there any way of quickly getting the fully qualified name of a class from within the editor?

So, if I have some code like

```
Element element = new Element();
```

I could quickly get the fully qualifed name of Element, for example, `com.whatever.Element`

Comment: Yes I have been looking for a shortcut for copy fully name of a class, including its package name, like "right click then Y" in eclipse. Sadly here seems no way to do this.

Comment: @ShedomWei see the answer with most upvotes, it's there for at least 6 years...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hover (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> and hover)

If I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hover over the class name `Element` with my mouse, I get a popup with the following information (assuming `Element` extends `AbstractElement` and implements `IElement`):

```
[intellij-module-name] com.whatever
public class Element extends AbstractElement
implements IElement
```

The package name after the module name on the first line, plus the name of the class itself, would give you the fully-qualified name in your head. You can also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Left Click on the `Element` class name to jump to its definition, where you could copy out the package declaration from the file if you need the actual text in the editor for whatever reason.

For macOS, hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> while hovering mouse pointer.

Comment: If you  `Ctrl`+Right click on the element and choose `Copy Reference` the fully qualified name will be copied to clipboard

Comment: Too bad you can't copy from that popup. Also it inserts a space between package name and class name. Idea sucks so much :(

Answer (score 51):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Edit | Copy Reference) on "Editor" in the code and you'll have the fully-qualified name in your clipboard.

Or alternatively just right-click on the code and select "Copy Reference".

Comment: Perfect! In Eclipse, I'd always do Ctrl+H to get the Find dialog, which had the fully-qualified class name in it, and then copy from there. IntelliJ doesn't seem to have the direct equivalent, but this is even better.

Comment: @Ray: in Eclipse you can always right click on the method or class and it will offer you an option to copy the fully qualified name.

Comment: How can I get the dots instead of slash?

Comment: @Hamedz you are doing something differently, I have dots no slashes...

Comment: On Ubuntu, these simply copy the name of the class for me, not the FQDN

Comment: When people are talking about a fully qualified name, do they mean something like`Vendor\Module\SomeClass`? I am getting `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/GetObjByEntityId.php:13`, which is not what I want, I want the former example

Comment: @Scott Anderson: Yes, the former string is meant. The latter is just the file/line opened in the editor, which happens when nothing smarter could be suggested. It's all language- and location-specific, and there might be bugs (usually easily fixable). So it makes sense to file an issue with details to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ or write to support.

Comment: Seriously in 2021 I don't want to be filling bugs to be able to easily get a class FQN instead of slashes

Comment: Looks like this is working, however, when you try to paste it in the same class or another, this is only pasting the class name and add it to the imports which is dumb IMO. Try to paste it in a String between quotes and it will paste the correct value. You can even see it with ctrl + shift + paste that it's trying to paste the FQDN but the autocomplete kicks in and ruins it.

Answer (score 11):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> when the cursor is inside the class name, will show you the class's package name and the Javadoc for that class. <kbd>Esc</kbd> will then close the window.

Comment: Cool shortcut, it keeps a dialog up instead of being an ephemeral popup too if you need it to stick around. Although it technically shows the package name, not the fully qualified name, but that's a minor detail.

Comment: @ajp15243 You are right about the package name - I've edited my answer.